# Ancient Latin font?

Tags: fonts

Everyone knows about "Times Ancient Roman", but is there something like "Times Old Roman", which I would like to use for typesetting a Latin epitaph:

[image]

I am not even sure I understand the minute differences between the typefaces, but they look different. I know that the `U` looks like a `V` though.

Comment: I think this is better-suited on [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: There is [Trajanus](http://www.fontspace.com/roger-white/trajanus-roman). Regular caps and petite caps. No lowercase letters. Lining figures, no old-style figures. Limited set of punctuation marks.

Comment: [This picture, click here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Brl.png) shows the Trajan font; `\usepackage{trajan}` and `\begin{trjnfamily}...\end{trjnfamily}`.

Comment: There is some similarity to the GoundyTwenty font: https://ct.mob0.com/Fonts/CharacterMap/GoudyTwenty.png

Comment: This "ancient latin font" was first used on the [pedestal](https://startlediguana.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/trajan_column_inscription.jpg) of [Trajan's_Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajan's_Column), better pictured [here](http://www.newcriterion.com/cm/images/articles/The-problem-with-Trajan-8368.jpeg). So look for [Trajan fonts](https://www.google.com/search?q=trajan+font&tbm=isch), there are lots to choose from.